# VPN type - only PPTP - no VPN or Import option.

Tags: openvpn

Says I need the correct plugin installed. Have installed Openvpn.

Regards
David

Answer (score 1):

Found that the following created the relevant entry option - 
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome

Comment: Can you mark this as answered? Thank you.